# issue on separating username and domain name from email address

Tags: mysql

I am using my sql to write sql query. So I have created a table called email.
I wanted to separate the email into username and domain name.I made the use of substring and instring but it gives me error message as:
Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'Instr'

The Sql query I have used is below:

```
select substr(email,1,Instr(email,'@',1,1)-1) as username,
substr(email, Instr(email,'@',1,1)+1) as domainname
from email;
```

Could you please me out?

Comment: alternately get the application code to separate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`instr()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) takes 2 arguments and not 4.
Change your code to this:

```
select 
  substr(email,1,Instr(email,'@')-1) as username, 
  substr(email, Instr(email,'@')+1) as domainname 
from email
```

You could also use [`substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
select 
  substring_index(email, '@', 1) as username, 
  substring_index(email, '@', -1) as domainname 
from email
```

Comment: thank you for the code, the code in working now. But one questions, I have seen in some cases there are 4 arguments for  instring like: lets take an example of a string value: This is a playlist. In this case, we we want the second and third occurence of the substring 'is' we use the code as: SELECT
  INSTR( 'This is a playlist', 'is', 1, 2 ) second_occurrence,
  INSTR( 'This is a playlist', 'is', 1, 3 ) third_occurrence
FROM
  dual; So, here I see the use of four arguments in instring. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In Mysql the function instr() takes 2 arguments. The code that you have seen is valid in Oracle.

Comment: Check this for Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm

Comment: Sure Thank You. I will look into it.